# Error 403 on Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

The URL

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[ID_OF_SPREADSHEET]?key=[MY_API_KEY]
```

What I get

```
   {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
      }
    }
```

At the moment, I have no Key Restriction on my API Key for the sake of testing.

[I've had a look at a past question that's been popular but no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920443/why-does-my-apps-script-deployed-as-api-executable-return-permission-denied)

Comment: have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949318/google-sheets-api-returns-the-caller-does-not-have-permission-when-using-serve

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to this [403 error in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) wherein you have insufficient permission. By that, you need authentication and authorization using OAuth. There are quickstart guides which has implementation in [JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js), [Python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python),etc.

To prove this, go to [auth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and get the permissions for 'Google Sheets API v4'. Follow the steps and place your URI request in Step 3. You shouldn't have problems performing operations after that.

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315266/google-sheets-api-v4-receives-http-401-responses-for-public-feeds/37342555#37342555) for additional reference on how to use OAuth Playground.

Answer (score 2):

i faced same issue in my electron app

i just did

```
https://console.developers.google.com/
```

then

```
choose library->google sheet->enable
```

thats it started working to me

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on here, have you checked that the user that you are authenticated as must have permission to the file. So check in the File->Share->Advanced and check if the Sharing settings have the email that you are logged in to in your application.

Comment: Yup. It's there.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and it turned out that I was trying to write to the sheet by using `readonly` scope

```
SCOPE_READ = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
```

Actually I need Read+Write scope (permissions) to write to the spreadsheet:

```
SCOPE_WRITE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

When you will be prompted by Google Accounts prompt for authorizing the app to access the sheets, you can see there what permissions your script has requested. Make sure they are the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

i face the same issue

i just go `https://console.developers.google.com` then `library->google sheet->enable` and Enabled the *Google Sheet API*

then i have open google sheet and follow below steps:

1. `Extension->Apps Script`
2. Click on Deploy button and select `Manage Deployments or new Deployments`
3. Edit Configuration detail and give authorize rights for **add, update, delete, view**
4. Click on Deploy

this is working for me.