# Vue3/Javascript: Google Sheets Api - 403 Forbidden/PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I created a key in the google cloud console. I even tried remaking it and using a the new one.

[image]

Im trying to use it like so:

```
export const getSheet= async () => {
      try {
          const sheetId ='xxxxxxx'
          const tabName = 'myTab'
          const accountKey = 'xxxxxxx'
          const url =' https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+ sheetId +'/values/'+tabName+'?key='+ accountKey
          console.log(url)
          const response = await fetch(url);
        console.log(response);
        return '';
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        console.log('finally');
      }
    };
```

The request being sent is:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxx/values/myTab?key=xxxxxxx
```

No matter what I do I get

```
error: {code: 403, message: "The caller does not have permission", status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"}
```

Ive refered to these stack overflow posts regarding the same issue with no luck

1. [Error 403 on Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806893/error-403-on-google-sheets-api)
2. [Google Sheets API V4 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009410/google-sheets-api-v4-403-error)
3. [Getting 403 from Google Sheets API using apikey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393986/getting-403-from-google-sheets-api-using-apikey)

Has anyone come across this and was able to fix it?

Thanks
-Coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look through the [Javascript Quickstart guide for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) for the OAuth Setup. And you can access the sheet using `Spreadsheet.values.get` method similar to this sample script on the provided URL reference.

```
async function listMajors() {
        let response;
        try {
          // Fetch first 10 files
          response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: 'SHEETID',
            range: 'SHEETRANGE',
          });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }
        const range = response.result;
        if (!range || !range.values || range.values.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No values found.';
          return;
        }
```

And just like what DazWilkin provided. Make sure that your app complies with [Google's OAuth2 policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow).

You can also test your request url first on a browser and see if it returns a JSON response of the sheet data. Tested this `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxx/values/myTab?key=xxxxxxx` format on a public sheet, and it returned the sheet data as long as it is set to 'Anyone with the link'

Comment: Holy cow. I got it. So when i was clicking "anyone with a link" All i was doing was copying it to the clipboard. I didnt realise it was another setting to with it to totally public.

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern Alright, if you're comfortable with setting the sheets privacy settings to Public then that should be all good